# Targeting tags inside of a div

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

How would I target tags inside of a div?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css">
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        function display(){
            var x = document.getElementById("hello");
            var y = x.getElementsByTagName("ul").getElementsByTagName("li").getElementsByTagName("a"); 
            if (x.style.display == "none"){
                x.style.display = "block";
            } else{
                x.style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    </script>
    <button onclick="display()">Press</button>
    <div class="test" id="hello">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This just gives me an error of

> ncaught TypeError: x.getElementsByTagName(...).getElementsByTagName is not a function
> at display (test.html:14)
> at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (test.html:22)

Comment: `x.getElementsByTagName("ul")` returns a `NodeList` (like an Array), not a single element. But you can just use `querySelectorAll`.

Comment: it works as it is, I use chrome

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
function display(){
    var x = document.getElementById("hello");
    var y = x.getElementsByTagName("ul").getElementsByTagName("li").getElementsByTagName("a"); 
    if (x.style.display == "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else{
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

to this:

```
function display(){
    const testDiv = document.getElementById("hello");
    const anchors = testDiv.querySelectorAll(':scope > ul > li > a');
    for( const a of anchors ) {
        a.style.display = ( a.style.display == 'none' ) ? 'block' : 'none';
    }
}
```

---

That said, you really don't need any scripts at all: the page does the same thing without any JavaScript:

```css
#trigger1 { display: none; }
label[for] {
    appearance: button;
    -webkit-appearance: button;
}

#trigger1:not(:checked) ~ * div#hello > ul > li > a {
    display: none;
}

#trigger1::checked ~ * div#hello > ul > li > a {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<input id="trigger1" type="checkbox" class="trigger t1" checked="checked" />
<label for="trigger1">Press</button>
<div class="test" id="hello">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined`